# How to check for Expired UILocalNotifications?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilocalnotification

Hi can anyone please Explain How to check for Expired UILocalNotifications and cancel the notifications?

Comment: You want to do this while scheduling the notification or while opening the app?

Comment: i want to do cancellin in applicationDidEnterBackground function

Comment: What you are trying to do seems meaningless. See my updated answer below.

Comment: basically in my app i have start date and enddate b/w those dates i need to show the notifications and after the enddate i need to cancel that notification please can you provide any tutorial for start date and end date

Comment: So, You have a notification that fires daily or on some intervals from 01-10-2011 to 14-10-2011. If the the current date is 14-10-2011 then you want to cancel the notification after it is fires today?

Comment: yes after 14-10-2011 i want to cancel the notification

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3624/discussion-between-ram-and-emptystack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"You can not cancel an expired notification, because it is already expired/fired".**

When you schedule the notification, if the *fireDate* is *nil* or a *past date* then the notification will be fired immediately. So, schedule the notification for the future dates alone.

By the time *applicationDidEnterBackground* delegate is called all the notifications(which you refer as *"Expired Notifications"*) would have got fired.

Once a notification is fired it will be automatically removed if it is not an recurring notification.

**To cancel a local notification on a date**

Use the following code to cancel a notification if the last date has reached. Call this method either from `didReceiveLocalNotificaiton:` method or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

```
- (void)stop:(UILocalNotification *)localNotif ifLastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {

    NSTimeInterval ti = 24*60*60; // One day
    NSDate *expiryDate = [lastDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:ti];
    NSDate *nextFireDate = [localNotif.fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:ti];

    if ([nextFireDate compare:expiryDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }
}
```

The *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* method,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    // Other Codes Here

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");

    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        if (notification) [self stop:notification ifLastDate:aDate]; // aDate is the last date you want to check
    }

    // Other Codes Here

    return YES;
}
```

The *didReceiveLocalNotification:* method,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    [self stop:notification ifLastDate:aDate]; // aDate is the last date you want to check
}
```

Note that you can cancel a local notification only when the app is running. You can not cancel a notification if the app is not running. The above code will cancel the notification only if the the app is opened by tapping the *action button* after the notification is fired on *`lastDate`*. If not, the notification will be cancelled when the app is opened by tapping *action button* on a notification that fires after the *lastDate*.

Comment: So, You have a notification that fires daily or on some intervals from 01-10-2011 to 14-10-2011. If the the current date is 14-10-2011 then you want to cancel the notification after it is fires today?

Comment: hi can you please explain this concept

Comment: Thanks for the code can i use the above code in applicationDidEnterBackground function

Comment: hi i placed breakpoint to the above function the control is not coming to the above code

Comment: You should call this method either from `didReceiveLocalNotificaiton:` method or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Comment: ya i placed [self stop:] but its showing some warning can you please put the syntax to call that function

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on Expired??? You can get the notification that are before expiry time(may b current time) by giving the timeinterval range.
You can definitely cancel notification using

`- (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`

Answer (score 0):

in the below mentioned delegate method you can check the date

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    if(notif.fireDate  Compare:[NSDate date]==NSOrderAscending)
    NSLog(@"Expired");
}
```

Comment: i think for this the application has to run continously but i don't want to run my app continously

Answer (score 0):

**If your UILocalNotifications increment the application icon badge number** (i.e. the number in the red circle on the top right of the app's icon), then there is a *ridiculously simple* way to check for unacknowledged UILocalNotifications: just check what the current `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{        
    int unacknowledgedNotifs = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber;
    NSLog(@"I got %d unacknowledged notifications", unacknowledgedNotifs);
    //do something about it...

    //You might want to reset the count afterwards:
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

}
```