# Expired IOS notifications appear again

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

We designed a new ios app that has local notification which works properly, and create notification without problem, and been fired. But the problem starts when the device is off for a while, and when the notification is disabled, because when the the device starts again or when the notification is enabled, the expired notifications appear again, but in fact they shouldn't appear because they are expired. This problem occurs in many devices and we cannot specify the models, as this problem occur in most of them occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Check your expired local notifications and cancel those expired notification.
Please refer below link 
[How to check for Expired UILocalNotifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484618/how-to-check-for-expired-uilocalnotifications)